# Accessing data from a REST API in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have a REST api from elasticsearch. I want to retrieve the data of a specific field. That is, I want to retrieve the data in the Gender field. What I have done is I have consume the rest service in AngularJS as follows. But nothing is appearing on the browser. Can somebody help to achieve what I want to display?

```
angular.module("view.index", ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/menuIndex/', {
        templateUrl: 'view-index/template/index.html',
        controller: 'NewController',
        controllerAs: 'newCtrl',
    });
}])

.controller('NewController', ['$timeout', 'overlayMessage', '$location', 'userInformation', '$http', '$scope','menuService', function ($timeout, overlayMessage, $location, userInformation, $http, $scope, menuService) {
    var myCtrl = this;


   myCtrl.Form = {};


   $http.get('http://admin:admin@localhost:9200/index1/_search?_source=Gender').
        success(function(data) {
            myCtrl.json = data;

        });
    }]);
```

The GET api `http://admin:admin@localhost:9200/index-data/_search?_source=Gender` returns me a `json` body like this:

```
{
  "took": 17,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 30003,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type": "tbl",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Gender": "Female"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type": "tbl",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Gender": "Male"
        }
      }
```

And in my front end, I want to access the data in the Gender field like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="menuNsmCtrl">   
        <div ng-repeat="json in json">
            <p>The ID is {{json.Gender}}</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try replacing line in `success` callback with `myCtrl.json = data.hits.hits;` and attribute `ng-repeat` set to `json in newCtrl.json`

Answer (score 0):

First use `then` instead of `success` to catch the data. `success` is deprecated since the angular version 1.4

```
$http.get('http://admin:admin@localhost:9200/index1/_search?_source=Gender').
        then(function(response) {
            myCtrl.json = response.data;

        });
}]);
```

now since you use `controllerAs` syntax you need to use the reference variable in the html also

```
<div ng-controller="NewController as myCtrl">   
        <div ng-repeat="json in myCtrl.json.hits.hits">
            <p>The ID is {{json['_source'].Gender}}</p>    
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, 

It does not work. I am getting the following errors in console: 

1. Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'menuNsmCtrl' is not a function, got Object

2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/index1/_search?_source=Gender. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: @jones Is your angluar code hosted on `localhost:9200`? You are getting a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) error which means that you are probably trying to access a resource in a different host/port and the server hosting the resource doesn't have CORS configured (is not configured to allow cross-domain requests).

Comment: The CORS issues is resolved. The issue that I am getting is `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'menuNsmCtrl' is not a function, got Object` and `GET http://localhost:9200/index1/_search?_source=Gender 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: I guess the first line of the template should be `<div ng-controller="NewController as myCtrl">`